# SOQL Query Question?

Tags: dynamic-soql

If I have 3 parent records which each have 3 child records, and I have a list of the parent Ids off the child records so there would be 3 duplicates of 3 ids, would the SOQL for the parent object such that Id IN ParentIdList return 3 or 9 rows?

Comment: You will have as many records as you have in DB, which means, you cannot have records with same ids in DB? s there will be 3 rows in result. It is easy to be tested in several lines of codes. What was the thing you have stuck with?

Answer (score 4):

SOQL will never return duplicate rows, so the answer is that you'll get 3 records.

It's hard to say exactly how Salesforce deals with something like the following

```
List<Id> myIds = new List<Id>{Id1, Id2, Id3, Id1, Id2, Id3};
List<MyObject> myObjs = [SELECT Name FROM MyObject WHERE Id IN :myIds];
```

...but I suspect that removing duplicate filters is probably part of the query optimization process that runs after you submit the query but before it is actually executed on the back-end of Salesforce.